# How to define an assignment operator in Scala?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, operators

For example, I have defined a `+*` operator for weighted sum in the following wrapper class for `Double`:

```
  class DoubleOps(val double: Double) {
    def +*(other: DoubleOps, weight: Double): DoubleOps =
      new DoubleOps(this.double + other.double * weight)
  }

  object DoubleOps {
    implicit def DoubleToDoubleOps(double: Double) = new DoubleOps(double)
  }
```

With this definition, I can have the following calculation:

```
var db: DoubleOps = 1.5
import DoubleOps._
db = db +* (2.0, 0.5)
println(db)
```

Is there a way I can calculate `db` using an assignment operator to get the result, like to define a `+*=`, so that I can use:

```
db +*= (2.0, 0.5)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import scala.languageFeature.implicitConversions

class DoubleOps(var double: Double) {
  def +*(other: DoubleOps, weight: Double): DoubleOps =
    new DoubleOps(this.double + other.double * weight)

  def +*=(other: DoubleOps, weight: Double): Unit = {
    this.double = this.double + other.double * weight
  }
}

object DoubleOps {
  implicit def DoubleToDoubleOps(double: Double) = new DoubleOps(double)
}

val d: DoubleOps = 1.5

d +*= (2.0, 0.5)
```

Comment: We all should take this as an opportunity to meditate on the distinction between reassignment and mutation.

Comment: Yes that is one subtlety. The OP wants mutation but he wrote assignment.

Comment: Right, reassignment cannot be a method AFAIK because it doesn't change something within the object, it changes something in the environment.

Comment: It's because in the book "Scala for the impatient" the author calls it "assignment operator".

Comment: @Tyler提督九门步军巡捕五营统领 I see. I think I remember that part of the book.